# Can you tell me about the use of the hyphen and apostrophe in these sentences?

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe, compounds, compound-nouns

> Virat-ton brings the team to the semifinals.
>
> Potato prices have risen up sharply.

The first sentences could say *Virat's ton* and similarly *Potato's prices*. Another example:

> Potato-peels taste amazing.

What's the rule?

Comment: The hyphen is used to link words to form an adjective, for example: *my two-year-old brother*. That being said, I don't understand what *Virat-ton* is supposed to mean. A potato can't own a price, so you can't use the possessive.

Comment: Virat ton means a lot of runs scored by Virat in game of cricket.

Comment: Is *-ton* as used same as this definition, [*ton*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ton): ton (3) "*noun, slang, mainly British* a score or achievement of a hundred, esp a hundred miles per hour, as on a motorcycle"? If so you should add the definition to your question. Also is your example actual usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of your first sentence, you do not need to a descriptive compound name. But, you want to say sb's action brought the team something. However, in the case of inanimate object it is possible to have such nouns. Compare:

> Computer keyboard, not Computer's keyboard
>
> Rooney's goal, not Rooney goal

In terms of your first sentence, based on my grammar book [1], I can say that:

We use **noun+'s+ noun**:

1. when the first name is the user (a person or animal) of the item in the second noun.
2. when the item in the second noun is produced by the thing (often an animal) in the first noun.
3. When we talk about parts of people or animals.

Thus,  you should say:

> Potato prices have risen up sharply.

---

**Reference:**

[1] "Cambrdige Advanced Grammar in Use, Unit 43, Page 86.

Comment: Potato's peels correct?

Comment: Nope, By the way, I am not a native English Speaker.